# Write a File in Phone Memory using J2ME

Tags: java, file-io, java-me

I have just downloaded the Samsung SDK 1.2 for Java Development.

Now, it's pure based J2ME architecture, so I have a requirement to store some files inside the memory for my application usage.

That file can have a .csv extension, so for that I have tried JSR 75's FileConnection class with following piece of code :

```
try {
            FileConnection fconn = (FileConnection) Connector.open("file:///CFCard/newfile.txt");
            if (!fconn.exists()) {
                fconn.create();  // create the file if it doesn't exist
            }
            fconn.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("exception = "+ioe);
        }
```

But in this case, it's giving me following exception :

```
exception = java.io.IOException: Root is not accessible
```

So, I don't exactly, I am on the right track or not..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The roots available to you vary between devices.  Read the [JSR 75 documentation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=75) -- the method `FileSystemRegistry.listRoots()` will be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about that "CFCard". For example, on my phone, I think it would be `"file:///E:/newfile.txt"`

I'll try to do some research about this

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.... Actually I got the following link where I have found out the sample application for the same : http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=3&cntsId=5401&listReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fcms%2Fcnts%2Fknowledge.list.do%3FplatformId%3D3&linkType=0

Comment: Here is a nice link: http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/ttips/fileconnection/